# Colored buttons don't show up when jGRASP is run on mac?

Tags: java, macos, jgrasp

i'm not sure if I'm allowed to ask questions not explicitly regarding code on StackOverflow, but I currently have a java program involving colored buttons. At school, when I run it on a computer that isn't a Mac, jGRASP shows the colors and runs perfectly fine, but on my personal Macbook, the buttons are white and turn grey when clicked, regardless of what I set the color to. So I know it can't be my code, unless there's a special method especially for Macs, which is doubtful. Is this a problem with all Macs? I'm using the

```
     array[x].setForeground(Color.blue);
```

method to set everything. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This may depend on the Look&Feel and Java version. In general, a component doesn't have to pay any attention to its foreground color.